# When upgrader_process_complete hook will not trigger?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've created a simple Code Snippet (with run everywhere) to test the upgrader_process_complete hook.   I cannot get it to trigger on plugin updates or plugin activation.  I see no errors with wp_debug true.

```
function my_custom_upgrader_process_complete($upgrader_object, $options) {
    error_log('upgrader_process_complete triggered!');
}
add_action('upgrader_process_complete', 'my_custom_upgrader_process_complete', 999, 2);
```

---

I'm using a very basic Wordpress installation with only Code Snippets and Elementor plugin with the Hello theme.  Any ideas on troubleshooting?  I also tried it with child theme in functions.php.

Comment: Solved... sort of.   I found that if I turn on define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ) then I get these error_log entries sent to ( wp-content/debug.log ).  I can use this but why weren't they going to the error_log file?